# How can I hang the "active" class only on the current route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I have such routes:

```
this.route('posts', function() {
  this.route('index', { path: '/' })
  this.route('show', { path: '/:post_path' }, function() {
    this.route('people', { path: '/people' })

    this.route('files', function() {
      this.route('images', { path: '/images' })
      this.route('videos', { path: '/videos' })
    })
  })
}),
```

I have a problem with the class "active".

Take, for example, this link:

```
http://localhost:4200/posts/1-best-post/files/images
```

In this case, the class "active" will hang on two links - on `posts.show.files.images` and on `posts.show`.

How to make the class "active" only for `posts.show.files.images`?

**ADDITION**

Apparently the problem is not only with the class "active". But with the templates. The children use the "show" template.

Could you please explain how to properly describe such nested routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is because ember has a hidden [index route](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_index-routes) for each nested function in the router.

Your route file actually expands out to look like this.

```
this.route('posts', function() {
  this.route('index', { path: '/' })
  this.route('show', { path: '/:post_path' }, function() {
    this.route('index', { path: '/' }) #New
    this.route('people', { path: '/people' })

    this.route('files', function() {
      this.route('index', { path: '/' }) #New
      this.route('images', { path: '/images' })
      this.route('videos', { path: '/videos' })
    })
  })
}),
```

When you define the link-to path, I'm going to assume that you specify it exactly as it looked, rather than using the hidden index.

```
# Don't do this
{{#link-to 'posts.show' "1234"}}Posts Show{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'posts.show.files.images' "1234"}}Images Show{{/link-to}}
# Do this
{{#link-to 'posts.show.index' "1234"}}Posts Show{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'posts.show.files.images' "1234"}}Images Show{{/link-to}}
```

This [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e29dee07eecbe009f27e2782ec811e19?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) shows an example of the issue you're having.    The top section shows the issue you're experiencing.  The bottom section shows the corrected links.

Similarly,  the show.hbs route you're using is going to be considered a wrapper for ALL routes under show.
If you don't want the content of show when you're looking at files or images,  move the logic and display into posts/show/index.js and posts/show/index.hbs

Comment: You are right about everything. Thank you very much! I have one question left - How in the "people" get the "post_path" parameter? In the "model()" method nothing is transferred.

Comment: For some reason I could not create a gist. This is a screenshot of what I wrote about: https://prnt.sc/k5c30r. The content is "`{}`".

Comment: I found the second way: `this.paramsFor('posts.show').post_path`. I think this issue is exhausted. Thank you again!

Comment: That's right Colibri - paramsFor is what you use to get the parameters for parent/grandparent routes.